# Sum() in python

Tags: python, sum

I have been trying to be comfortable with the sum() in python, I did understand the basic function of sum but as a mathematica backgroud,I was just inquistive to know can we use sum in python in the same way like we do in mathematica for example consider this mathematica module:

```
Sq[a_, b_] := Module[{m, n}, m = Max[a, b]; n = Min[a, b];Sum[(m - r + 1) (n - r + 1), {r, 1, n}]]
```

Now,could it be possible to write the sum part like that? I mean:

```
Sum[(m - r + 1) (n - r + 1), {r, 1, n}]
```

Trying to covert this in python,I think of something like this:

```
sum((m - r + 1) (n - r + 1) in xrange(1,n+1))
```

but doesn't seems to be working! so my question how to get it work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sum((m - r + 1) * (n - r + 1) for r in xrange(1,n+1))
```

1. There's no implicit multiplication between integers, so you need the `*`.
2. `f(x) for x in xes` is the general format of a list comprehension, where you want `x` to iterate through every element of `xes`, and give back the value `f(x)`.

Comment: I just happen to figure it out that `sum((m - r + 1) * (n - r + 1) for r in range(1,n+1))` too works.

Comment: The difference between the two is that in Python 2.x, `range` returns an actual list, which may be quite wasteful of memory if the list is large. `xrange` is an iterable which generates the numbers in order rather than actually returning a real list. (In Python 3, `xrange` goes away and `range` becomes a memory efficient iterable)